# Issues with installing sqlite3 in NPM

Tags: npm-install, discord.js, node-sqlite3, commando, node-pre-gyp

So I'm just setting up my Discord bot in a new machine. I used the latest Node version in LTS and I have Windows Build Tools installed.

But doing `npm install`, everything is going well until the part when the sqlite3 package is being installed. I have a log here for reference: https://pastebin.com/ktJ8VyZY

And another log straight from PowerShell: https://pastebin.com/d232rjJY

Before I had issues with Python and that has been resolved but right now I cannot pinpoint exactly what is the problem and I've been reading all lines related to `gyp` and the problem isn't really clear for me so I'm here if anyone can pinpoint the exact problem and the ways to solve it.

Thank you.

Package.json if needed: https://pastebin.com/ACh0mQRe

Comment: I'm not fully understanding how npm works, but you have a sqlite 2.9 dependency in your package.json, while discord commando has a peerDependency for sqlite 3.0. You should try to remove your sqlite dependecy, or use the same version, this might help you solve this problem